# What resources are there to create a WPS from a web app?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, rest, ogc, wps, soap

I am developing a web app using the Weight of Evidence method and I need to create a web processing service out of it or enable it for web processing services.

The code is in C# and includes an engine file, some GUI related files, and a plethora of different files. Are there any in particular I should look for? Or I guess are there any particular frameworks or wrapper classes for this transaction? Are they intuitive or is there any workaround?

Essentially this will take some inputs as necessary from a user and apply it to a programmatic weight of evidence formula and return a result.

Based on what I can see from the code there are raster analysis frames and a variety of different files I'm not entirely familiar with. It wouldn't serve any purpose to post any code as it is a large file that I don't have experience with. I can say it uses the following libraries as well as other system libraries:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesRaster;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoAnalyst;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.AnalysisTools;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.SpatialAnalyst;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Display;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.GeoDatabaseUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
```

However, according to the project details I need to find a workaround to not using any ESRI packages.

Comment: Are you looking to create an OGC Web Processing Service, or just using the term web processing service in a more generic sense?  Which version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to create an OGC Web Processing Service. I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Is ready your Web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS 10.1 [help topic for WPS Services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//015400000327000000) contains a [tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tutorial_Publishing_a_WPS_service/0154000004rp000000/).

Before publishing it as a GP service, you'll need to package your code as a [custom geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000049w000000).  You will also need an ArcGIS server license.

[image]